# Expanding a `div` while taking its children `max-width` into consideration

Tags: javascript, html, css

My front-end skills are poor, so does my English expression. Sorry ahead.

---

I have these several `div`s (some `color`s and `margin`s are added as some kind of visual assistance):

```html
<html>
    <header>
        <style>

.outer-container {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px deeppink dashed;
}

.inner-container {
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px deeppink dotted;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.content0 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 1px red solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.content1 {
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="outer-container" style="width: 100%" align="center">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="content0">Placeholder</div>
                <div class="content1">Placeholder</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are my expected behaviors:

1. The `outer-container` has some kind of "externally appointed" width (`width: 100%` in this example, but not limited to this circumstance).
2. The `content0` is expected to have a minimum width for displaying its content. The `content1` is expected to expand horizontally and occupy its "container"'s space, at most `500px`.
3. The `inner-container` is expected to expand and occupy its "container"'s space, while *considering the maximum width of its children*. In this example, I expected it to expand  until `content1` reaches its `max-width`. Then, `inner-container` is aligned to the center of `outer-container`.

> [image: Narrow circumstance]
>
> Fig1: when `outer-container` is narrow, `inner-container` simply fills the `outer-container`.
>
> [image: Wide circumstance]
>
> Fig2: when `outer-container` gets wider, `inner-container` expands until its children stop expanding, and then `inner-container` gets to the center of `outer-container`. This picture was made by `mspaint`, not really I know how to implement it with HTML/CSS.

However, I bumped into troubles when trying to implement the third item. I've tried many combinations and searched over again. But for each attemption , either `inner-container`   is not expanded at all, or `inner-container` expands and eats up `outer-container`. Is it possible to implement this with HTML and CSS (and JavaScript if really needed)? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could get is https://jsfiddle.net/ne9phs5y/.

The `content0` and `content1` behave as expected but unfortunately `inner-container` fills the entire `outer-container` which might or might not be a problem. The most important part was setting [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) of `content1` to 500px.